# forest - Change style of all last edges

Tags: forest

I would like to set all the "last" edges in blue colour. What is the simplest way to do that? I would need to have references to the edges pointing to nodes without any child.

[image]

Here is the code used.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest} 
  for tree = {math content},
  where n children = 0 {tier = word, blue} {}
  [243
    [3   [3^1]]
    [81
      [9   [3^2]]       
      [9   [3^2]]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `edge=blue` to option `where n children ...`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
  \begin{forest}
    for tree = {
      math content,
      where n children = 0 {tier = word, blue, edge=blue} {},
    }
    [243
      [3   [3^1]]
      [81
        [9   [3^2]]
        [9   [3^2]]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Considering @cfr comments, you can write tree options as:

```
...
  \begin{forest}
    for tree = {
      math content,
      },
    where n children = 0 {tier = word, blue, edge=blue} {}, % <---
...
```

i.e. extend your original code with proposed extension with option with `edge=blue`, or instead `where` use `if`:

```
  \begin{forest}
    for tree = {
      math content,
      if n children = 0 {tier = word, blue, edge=blue} {},
      },
...
```

With use one of this changes the compilation time become shorter, which would avoid walking through the tree again for each node in the tree. This may become important when in document you have a lot of trees.

Explanation is given in @cfr comment.

Comment: Thanks for this proposition, but this uses a "hard hand" setting. I would like to avoid this...

Comment: @projetmbc, see edited version of answer.

Comment: Too simple for me... :-) Such a shame. ;-)

Comment: @projetmbc, don't be so self-critical. I didn't succeed in my first try either...

Comment: It's second degree humour... ;-)

Comment: @projetmbc If you have a lot of trees like this in a document, you might want to look at ways to speed up the `where` thing, but only if you have enough to noticeably affect compilation time.

Comment: @cfr Can you explain the optimizations to be applied? Optimization is always a good thing, unless it leads to an unreasonably complicated code.

Comment: @projetmbc In general, you don't want to use `where` inside the scope of `for tree` because you're multiplying the walks through the tree by the number of nodes, which might be a lot of walks! So it would make more sense to use `if` here, which would avoid walking through the tree again for each node in the tree. The original code is better in this respect, too, because the `where` is not in the scope of `for tree` so you only walk the tree twice. Using `for tree` and `if` would walk only once, but twice is much better than 1 + the number of nodes in the tree.

Comment: @projetmbc tldr: just substitute `if` for `where` in Zarko's answer.

Comment: @cfr, thank you very much!

Comment: @cfr Good proposition!